# How to make the background of a JCheckBox transparent?

Tags: java, swing

Is there an easy way to make the background of a `JCheckBox` transparent? The box itself and the text should both be ordinary colored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
setOpaque(false);
```

That line will make the background of the `JCheckBox` not be drawn.  It will be the color of whatever `Component` it is on.

If you are subclassing a `JCheckBox`, just place that line in the constructor.  Otherwise call it on an instance of the `JCheckBox`.

Comment: Using GTK look and feel, when clicking the JCheckbox, the background of the JCheckbox goes opaque. Regardless of this setting.